# React Native Scroll View and Flex Children

Tags: react-native

I am having a lot of trouble working with a scroll view and flex dimensions. Basically the initial screen of the app should show a top side "banner" while the bottom is the "content".

The content is going to contain many "cards" that each contain information, and users will be able to scroll down to see the next card, and the next, and etc.

However, the flex property does not seem to be working at all, and I am not even able to create the proper sizes for the "banner" section and the "content" section.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput
{ from 'react-native';


import RestaurantCard from './common/RestaurantCard';

export default class MemberArea extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchText: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle = {styles.contentContainer}>
        <View style={styles.banner}>
          <TextInput style={styles.search}
            underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
            placeholder="Search for Restaurants"
            textAlign= 'center'
            textAlignVertical='center'
            returnKeyType="search"
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.dropdown}>
          {"What's nearby V"}
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.cards}>
          <RestaurantCard />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contentContainer:{
    flexGrow: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  cards:{
    flex:3,
    backgroundColor:'#000000'
  },
  banner: {
    flex:15,
    backgroundColor: '#F36B45',
    paddingBottom: 80
  },
  search:{
    marginTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    paddingTop: 5,
    height: 30,
    marginHorizontal: 40,
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)'
  },
  dropdown:{
    color: 'black',
    fontWeight:'900',
    fontSize:24,
    margin:30
  }


});
```

UPDATE: As seen in the comments below, I surrounded my scrollview with another view. I gave the Parent view Flex:1. The problem I run into now is as follows:

If I give the scrollview contentcontainerstyle flexGrow: 1, then the scrolling works as normal, but I cannot give the children sections of the scrollview space dimensions with flex values. However, if I give the scrollview flex:1 (rather than flexGrow), then I can give space dimensions to the children sections, but the scrolling function is disabled. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean by replicate my problem?

Comment: replicate your code in a sandbox like https://codesandbox.io/ or in expo

Comment: This is a link. Some of the style elements are not working but (like aligning text to center) but I believe that is trivial. Much of the format is very rough so we can simply see where the formatting should be

https://codesandbox.io/s/9lorl8o9wo

Comment: can you share a screenshot of your actual issue also, please and why `flex:15` ?

Comment: That was just an arbitrary number so I could see if any effects of the flex were occurring. They did not

Comment: Problem is with the flex property only I guess. To see how flex works, check here https://flexboxfroggy.com/ and https://yogalayout.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue you have is you set content inside `memberArea` to grow according to the content but outside the `memberArea`, it's fixed. Add `flex: 1` style to `View` in `App`.

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}> // App
```

Then you don't need to set `contentContainerStyle` for the `ScrollView`

Why do you set `flex: 15`? Check the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#flex) first.

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5xrwvpj6lp)

Comment: I was tinkering with your codesandbox and altering the flex values didn't seem to change the amount of space that each area was taking up. Am I missing something here? Also, I am not seeing what part of the documentation I might be misinterpreting, would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Josh Do you want the content to be able scroll separately?

Comment: No each content/card you would scroll past. Unless you mean separate from the banner area above? I think for that I haven't really decided yet but for now I'm going with them scrolling together

Comment: Yes meant separating from banner. But the code works fine like this to me. https://ibb.co/kuFTpJ

Comment: I guess a more specific problem I might be encountering: How would I be able to set the banner/content dimensions so that the banner goes down to 40% of the initial screen, and the content goes down to the rest of the initial screen. Of course, with the functionality of being able to scroll past this initial screen to see more content. I am unable to do this by adjusting the flex numbers on your codesandbox

Comment: After tinkering a bit more, I added a view around the scroll view with a flex of 1, and also included the view with a flex of 1 in the App.js file. If I make the scrollview have a flexGrow: 1, then the scrolling works, but the flex ratios do not. However, if I make the scrollview have flex:1, then the flex ratio dimensions work, but the scrolling does not. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Josh Can you provide your current progress in a sandbox?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. It's been a week and I still have not made any progress since my last sandbox. My last comment still remains true. I simply added a contentContainerStyle with flexGrow:1 within a parent View with flex:1.

If I set flexGrow:1, the scrolling works but the dimensions of the children of the scroll view cannot be changed using flex properties. But if I set the scrollview to flex:1, then scrolling is disabled, but the children can be sized using flex properties. I am still very lost and would love some help!

Answer (score 0):

Read the React-Native Docs on Flexbox properly.
[https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html][1]

You cannot set Higher values to child Views of the Parent Views.
If you want to divide the Parent's Flex: 1, into 2 children - you can do Flex:0.5 and Flex:0.5 to the two children.
If you want every child to have their own space, assign Flex: 1 to each of them.

Check the Docs and other articles on it for more details.